# Infinispan reports Degraded without any error s

Tags: infinispan

I have an infinispan setup, which works well on most of my environment. But recently one of them started to report that it is Degraded, on the management console.

There are no errors in the log files. And both of the hosts seem to be connected to each other. Domain controller reports both of the hosts connected.

I see some warnings in the log file, mostly related to the kernel memory limits.

I am out of ideas how to troubleshoot this thing. Can someone shed some light on it.

My environment is two host, one domain, running in docker files, on ubuntu.

Comment: What Infinispan version?